# Slice numpy array by chunks

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I need to slice an array (`aa`) given three values (`N1, N2, N3`) that define the slicing condition, as shown below:

```
import numpy as np

N1, N2, N3 = 200, 500000, 30
aa = np.random.uniform(0., 1., N1*N2)

bb = []
for i in range(N1):
    bb += list(aa[i * N2:(i * N2) + N3])
```

This code generates a new array `bb` following the rules:

1. the first `N3` elements of `aa`
2. jump `N2` elements and add the following `N3` elements of `aa`
3. repeat 2. until `aa` is exhausted

Can I perform this process faster via numpy indexing?

Comment: Why are you doing the `list(…)` here instead of just using the `aa[i * N2:(i * N2) + N3]` directly? The slicing is very efficient—you can make it a tiny bit _simpler_ with numpy, but it won't be any faster. But converting each slice to a list is very slow, and numpy isn't going to do anything to speed that up.

Comment: You mean jump N2-N3 elements?

Comment: @abarnert I'm sorry, what do you mean by "using the `aa[]` directly"? I use list to add this chunk to the final `bb` array. If I don't do that, I will just be adding elements, not extending the list.

Comment: @Gabriel Why do you want the final result to be a list? Why not let it be a chain of arrays, or a strided array?

Comment: I don't, that's just the way I found of concatenating the chunks of elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply reshape to `2D` and slice first N3 columns -

```
bb = aa.reshape(N1,N2)[:,:N3].ravel()
```

**When `N3` exceeds `N2`**

If `N3` exceeds `N2`, those `aa[i * N2:(i * N2) + N3]` would have overlaps across iterations. To solve for such a case, we can create sliding windows and then slice rows until we have enough lengths and then have a loop for the leftover windows -

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

starts = np.arange(len(aa), step=N2)
lens = len(aa) - np.arange(len(aa), step=N2)
rem_lens = lens[lens < N3]
m0 = lens < N3

l1 = N3*(~m0).sum()
l2 = rem_lens.sum() 
out = np.empty(l1+l2, dtype=aa.dtype)
out[:l1] = view_as_windows(aa,(N3))[::N2].ravel()
rem_starts = starts[m0]
ss = l1+np.r_[0,rem_lens.cumsum()]
for s,i,j in zip(rem_starts, ss[:-1], ss[1:]):
    out[i:j] = aa[s:]
```

Comment: Nice addition Divakar, than you again!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it more elegantly by reshaping the arrays. Start by making your initial array 2D:

```
N1, N2, N3 = 200, 500000, 30
aa = np.random.uniform(0., 1., (N1, N2))
```

Now it's just a matter of removing a chunk of size `N3` along the second dimension:

```
bb = aa[:, :N3]
```

If you need `bb` to be flat, make it so:

```
bb = aa[:, :N3].ravel()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NumPy's [`array_split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html#numpy.array_split) or [`split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html#numpy.split) to do the same thing a tiny bit more simply.

However, it's probably not going to be significantly more *efficient*.

Storing a bunch of array slices with `aa[i * N2:(i * N2) + N3]` is linear time in the number of slices. Doing that loop inside NumPy (and therefore in a C loop instead of a Python loop, assuming you're using CPython) will be a little faster. But unless you have a huge number of slices, that probably won't matter.

However, converting each slice to a list, with `list(aa[i * N2:(i * N2) + N3])`, and then extending an existing list, is very slow. It's probably going to take well over 99% of your total time, so optimizing the other 1% is irrelevant. And there's nothing NumPy can do to accelerate converting each slice to a list.

So, if you don't actually need a list, just stop calling `list`. You can just use a list of arrays and `chain` them together as needed, or you can build [a custom-strided array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.strides.html) out of the list of arrays, or you can just [`ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) the original array into the shape you want.

If you *do* need a list, that's inherently slow, and there's not much you can do about it.

Comment: But my final `bb` is not a "list of lists", but a single flat list. I'm not sure I understand this answer, sorry.

Comment: @Gabriel OK, edited. But the core point is the same: listifying is the slow part here. Extending a list is _also_ slow. And you don't need to do either of these.

Comment: Yes, I understand that which is why I asked about doing this via numpy slicing. What you mention (chain the numpy arrays) is also quite slow. Are you saying it would be faster than extending a list?

Comment: @Gabriel Yes, making a list of slice arrays and calling `chain` on it would be much faster than extending a list. Depending on what you're trying to do with `bb`, it may or may not be _useful_. if your ultimate goal is to use `bb` as an iterable, the chain won't iterate any faster than the list, but neither would a single array, and the chain will _build_ a lot faster. If your goal is to use `bb` as an array, then chaining won't do you much good, and you want one of the other options. Since it's not clear what you want to do with `bb`, it's hard to give more detail on how to do it.